# Derivation of Hamiltonian of EP-modulated microring resonator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, nanoscience

I'm an undergraduate in a nanophotonics lab and I need to derive something for my PI, but don't exactly know how to go about it. When reading a relevant paper, it was given that the Hamiltonian of an exceptional point modulated ring resonator was

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \omega - i \gamma & i \kappa_+ \\
  i \kappa_- & \omega - i \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\omega$ denotes the resonant frequency of the clockwise and counterclockwise modes of the ring resonator,  is the total loss of the microring in the form of  = $_p$ + $_i$ that includes both the intrinsic cavity loss $_p$ without any modulation on the microring, and the loss from the periodic loss modulation $_i$ ( here is the coupling constant), and $_{\pm}$ = ($_i$  ∓ $_r$)   denoting the coupling strength between counterclockwise and clockwise modes. How do we derive this Hamiltonian?

Comment: What paper is this equation taken from? Giving some context to your question might help others, even from different fields, to try and help you.

Comment: Please use mathjax instead of whatever unicode characters you're susing. On my computer a bunch of the symbols are blank and even when I go to edit them they render as squares.

Comment: @eranreches Unfortunately can't post the specific paper this is from since it's our project proposal (which shouldn't be made public) but I can post another paper which uses the same matrix formulation of the Hamiltonian: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.6320.pdf